# How do you set the "python" command to point to python2 instead of python3?

Tags: python

Due to my own stupidity, I somehow set the python command to run python 3 instead of the default python 2. How do I undo this? I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ python -V
Python 3.7.6
$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.6
```

Comment: it depends on your settings may be in your editor

Comment: I don't think it's my editor. My gnome-terminal won't open because of this issue.

Comment: I think you have to either : reinstall python 2 to override the name, or change the index for "python" to point at python2.

Comment: Without knowing what you did, it is nearly impossible to tell you how to undo it, given that the way a command ends up being executed in the Unix environment has so many degrees of freedom (PATH, different shells, aliases, symlinks, ...). If you are on Ubuntu, you might be better off asking on askubunu.com, in case Ubuntu has some way of forcing things back to the as-installed state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the alias python="/usr/bin/python2.7",for example :

```
alias python="/usr/bin/python3.3"
python
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 16 2013, 23:39:35)
```

You can also add this line in your .bashrc file

```
echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3.3" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: and add the above answer codes to the `~/.bashrc` file or run this command in the bash: `echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3.3" >> ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 4):

You can list all the version of Python installed and change the default Python version Try the following commands on terminal.

```
$:~# update-alternatives --config python
There are 4 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/local/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3     4         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   2         manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/python3     4         manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.7   3         manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/python3.8   4         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 4
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.8 to provide /usr/local/bin/python (python) in manual mode
```

Set the default python version using python version.
Finally, you can check the success of command as below.

```
root@kali:~# python --version
Python 3.8.2
```

It should show `Python 2.x` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

On most Unix-Linux systems, `python` is a link or a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. You should search where it is with `type python` and control what it is.

If it is a link or a symlink, just remove it and make it point to your installation of python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use `type python` to check what it points to, then check your `.bashrc` for two things:

- whether the path from `type python` is somewhere included in `PATH`
- whether you defined an alias for `python` somewhere

Answer (score -3):

To install python2, run:

`sudo apt install python-minimal`

To run python2,

`python2`